# How to determine if a file is empty without getting EOFException

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a file called manager.txt and read it. If it is empty (which it is) it will call a method to add things into it but I keep getting EOFException. I know the file is empty but it's just a part of a programI'm working on. How to determine a file is empty without getting EOFException

```
try(ObjectOutputStream outManager = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
    FileOutputStream("manager.txt"))){
         try(ObjectInputStream inManager = new ObjectInputStream(new 
             FileInputStream("manager.txt"))){
                 while(true){
                    manager.add((Manager)inManager.readObject());
                    if(manager.isEmpty()){
                      //A method to add
                    }
         }catch(IOException e){

         }
}catch (IOException e){

}
```

Comment: Your `inManager` will always be empty, you just (re)created in the previous line...

Comment: Replace if(manager.isEmpty()) with if(inManager != -1).

Comment: Why don't you look at the file size?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from file as follows:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("manager.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) 
    {
        while (fis.available() > 0) {
            Object obj = ois.readObject();
            if (obj instanceof Manager) {
                Manager manager = (Manager) obj;
                System.out.println(manager);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Basically, what you are looking for is `fis.available()`.

Comment: No, `fis.available()` is definitely not what he's looking for. I've been programming Java for +20 years and I've **never** needed to use `available()`. I know the name sounds like it's made for this purpose, but it's really not.